# RedHat Software collections and php72 and dblib

Tags: php, pdo, redhat

I am trying to use php72 on a Centos7 box via Red Hat Software Collections. Everything else seems to be working, but I can't get a connection to SQL Server database via dblib. Earlier I have used remi (on another server) but RHSC seemed somehow more trustworthy.

I thought the package with dblib should be rh-php72-php-pdo-dblib but there isn't that package. I have tried to search all around but nothing helpful surfaced. Am I the only one trying to use that combination or what?

wbr hank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the package with dblib should be rh-php72-php-pdo-dblib but
>   there isn't that package.

Indeed rh-php72-php-pdo-dblib doesn't exists on official Red Hat Software Collections, because it depends on **freetds** library which is not available on RHEL.

For now, my repository is the only solution.

I also recommend you to read [Microsoft SQL Server from PHP](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/09/20/Microsoft-SQL-Server-from-PHP)

Using **pdo_sqlsrv** (using Microsoft library) can be a better solution than **pdo_dblib** (using freetds).

> RHSCL seemed somehow more trustworthy.

Indeed, RHSCL is an official Red Hat supported product, while "remi" is a community driven repository, with only "best effort" support.

Comment: Actually, I meant with more trustworthy referring yum update, which is a bit trickier with remi collection, not the software itself. But thanks, seems I have to retract the installation to your repository.

Comment: And probably I have to stick with dblib as there are a ton of libraries I am using utilizing it

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue of unable to find pdo_dblib  after upgrading to php 7.X.

We use the below procedure to load pdo_dblib driver on Centos 7.

download source of php from php.net and untar it.

cd php-7.2.X/ext/pdo_dblib/

```
( make sure freetds and freetds-devel package are installed )
```

yum install freetds freetds-devel

phpize

php -v

./configure 
   ( if got error create below soft link )

ls -l /usr/lib64/libsybdb.so
   ln -s /usr/lib64/libsybdb.so /usr/lib/libsybdb.so

./configure

```
   make

   make install 

echo extension=pdo_dblib.so > /etc/opt/rh/rh-php72/php.d/pdo_dblib.ini
```

cat  /etc/opt/rh/rh-php72/php.d/pdo_dblib.ini

Comment: Forget to mention that we installed the PHP-72 and other module via Software Collection. ( centos-release-scl.noarch repository )